# What is the best way to remove html5 video background for mobile users

Tags: javascript, html, responsive-design, html5-video, media-queries

EXPLANATION: A customer of mine wants to have a background video running on his responsive website. However he would also like to remove it for tablet/mobile users. I know this can be done with media queries, but the video would still load as part of the DOM and that is what i would like to prevent.

QUESTIONS:

1. Can the video element be removed using JavaScript/jQuery from the DOM when it loads view-port at certain widths?
2. Can the same video be recovered when if the view port is manually increased in with? (i suspect this is a bad approach)
3. Will a video with "display:none;" still affect loading/battery time on a tablet/mobile ?

Thanks you for you assistance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [Stack Overflow: How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [Jon Skeet's Question Checklist](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist.aspx) to find out how to ask a good question that will generate good useful, answers.

Answer (score 2):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514784/what-is-the-best-way-to-detect-a-handheld-device-in-jquery) to detect if you're on a mobile device.

Then, using this test, you can `.hide()` your element using jQuery, or set its `src` attribute to `""`, to be sure it's not downloading.

Comment: Thanks Jb i think that will be the best solution :)

Comment: I would like to note this will not prevent the video from being downloaded by the user.

Comment: Use modernizr or js to detect if video element is available, and then don't load the video if that video element isn't valid.

Answer (score 2):

Based on mobile dimensions use `$('video').remove()`. this will removes the DOM element from webpage. so it will not render in html.

Answer (score 1):

not sure if this might help but this snippet will stop video getting played on mobile devices also you can mute the audio here and it should show fallback img here.

```js
const video = document.querySelectorAll('video')
              video.forEach(data=>{
                data.volume = 0 //mute audio
                console.log(data);
                  if (window.innerWidth <= 768) {
                      
                      data.autoplay=false; or //data.remove()
                  } else {
                      data.play();
                  }
                })
```

Comment: The post mentioned they want to avoid loading the video entirely - "but the video would still load as part of the DOM and that is what i would like to prevent."

Comment: data.remove() will totally remove the video element then we will need to add fallback img for that though

Answer (score 0):

You could also use css.
This is much easier.

```
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 320px) 
  and (max-device-width: 480px)
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
    video {
        display:none;
    }
}
```

Then have an image with a negative z-index, that way when the video is not displayed, the image will appear.