# Prevent html5 video element from being loaded on touch devices.

Tags: css, html, responsive-design, html5-video

I'm currently working on making a fullscreen video background. Usually for touch devices (iPad, iPhones, etc.) I would just hide the video element with css and display an image instead.

Out of curiosity I went to see what responsive solutions different websites are using for their html5 video backgrounds. That's when I noticed that AirBnB is not loading the html5 video element at all on touch devices (I tested on iPad and iPhone, I havn't tested on android yet). If you inspect the website on a touch device you will notice that the video element is completely "gone".

So my question is, **what is the best way to prevent html5 videos from being loaded on touch devices?**

Preferably with php or jquery (I also have modernizr loaded to my site.).

Comment: Use CSS media queries. All the cool kids are.

Comment: https://github.com/VodkaBears/Vide

Comment: @JayBlanchard hahaha! That's what I have been doing all the time. This would not affect loading time (by loading the video)?

Comment: If the video is not referenced in the media query it will not be downloaded.

Comment: See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24609127/what-is-the-best-way-to-remove-html5-video-background-for-mobile-users - Detect video element and hide using a media query.

Answer (score 1):

In Javascript:

```
if("ontouchstart" in document.documentElement){
    var video = document.querySelectorAll("video")[0];
    var img = document.createElement("img");

    //set img attributes here

    video.parentNode.replaceChild(img, video);

}
```

The problem of CSS media queries is that you cannot detect touch devices directly.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest cross-browser method would be to have a placeholder element, like:

```
<img src="background-img.jpg" data-video-src="video.mp4" class="video-placeholder" />
```

You simply have a listener for clicks on your elements that have the style `video-placeholder` and replace with the html5 video element.

Something like:

```
$('body').on('click','.video-placeholder', function(event) {
  //Create video element
  var videoSrc = $(this).data('video-src');
  var video = $('<video></video>');
  video.load(function() { /*Do onload stuff*/ });
  video.attr('src',videoSrc);
  //Replace element
  $(this).replaceWith(video);
});
```

This is obviously a very simplified solution, but it gives you an idea how to handle it so you don't autoload a video unless the user wants to play it.